# Set precision of DecimalType returned by UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I have a DataFrame like this :

```
// +---------+-----------+
// | myString|   myDouble|
// +---------+-----------+
// |AAA      |2.0        |
// |BBB      |3.0        |
// |CCC      |1.0        |
// +---------+-----------+
```

And i want to apply an UDF to my dataframe to multiply `myDouble` column by a `BigDecimal` and then get a third column `myBigDecimal`

My UDF :

```
val myUDf : UserDefinedFunction = udf((d : Double) => {
  (BigDecimal.valueOf(d)*BigDecimal("1.100000000000000000000000000001")).setScale(30)
})
```

Then i apply my UDF :

```
df.withcolumn("myBigDecimal", myUdf(col("myDouble"))
```

Then i get for the first row : `myBigDecimal = 2.200000000000000000 //expected 2.200000000000000000000000000002`

I printed the schéma and i found out that the type of myBigDecimal is : `DecimalType(38,18)`

What can i do to get my expected result ? (30 digits scale)

i tried to cast :

```
df.withcolumn("myBigDecimal", myUdf(col("myDouble").cast(DecimalType(38,30)))
```

But i get the same result and the schema is still `DecimalType(38,18)`

EDIT : Solved by adding a return type to the UDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a UDF with a specified return type:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

spark.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.allowUntypedScalaUDF = true")

val myUdf = udf(
    (d : Double) => {(BigDecimal.valueOf(d)*BigDecimal("1.100000000000000000000000000001")).setScale(30)}, 
    DecimalType(38,30)
)

val df = spark.sql("select 2.0d as myDouble")
val df2 = df.withColumn("myBigDecimal", myUdf(col("myDouble")))

df2.show(false)
+--------+--------------------------------+
|myDouble|myBigDecimal                    |
+--------+--------------------------------+
|2.0     |2.200000000000000000000000000002|
+--------+--------------------------------+
```